# The “.is-invalid” class on the input field that has an error is not showing up with simple_form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add the .is-invalid class of the latest version of bootstrap on an input that has an error by adding the `error_html: { class: 'is_invalid'}` code on every input field that I have.

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <%= simple_form_for @user, url: signup_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :username, placeholder: 'Username', error_html: { class: 'is_invalid'} %>
      <%= f.input :password, placeholder: 'Password', error_html: { class: 'is_invalid'} %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: 'Confirmation', placeholder: 'Confirm Password', error_html: { class: 'is_invalid'} %>
      <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'Email', error_html: { class: 'is_invalid'} %>
      <%= f.button :submit, "Sign Up", class: "btn-primary btn-block" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried testing it but the class is not being added. I know that simple_form is working because I can see the full error messages in below screen shot and it's display is none because it needs that `.is-invalid` class to displayed as a block.

[image]

Comment: Did you try installing simple_form with bootstrap integration instead? `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`. If that does not work you should solve this by creating your own wrapper instead of duplicating `error_html: { class: 'is_invalid'}` all over your code.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers